# How to add external regressors in a MGARCH-DCC model

Tags: r, garch

For my research, I am using the MGARCH-DCC model using the rmgarch package in R. However, this package only allows for external regressors in the mean and variance equation, but not directly in the DCC model. I have found a paper that implements a so-called DCCX model (Prange, 2021), however I don't know how to program this model. My question consists of two parts:

1. Is there a programming package that allows directly implementing the external regressors?
2. Is there a other way to test the significance of external regressors with regards to the dynamic conditional correlations (except for OLS regressions)?
3. If not, how could I implement the DCCX model? (I already have the standardized residuals of the GARCH model)

paper
Prange, Philipp. "Does online investor attention drive the co-movement of stock-, commodity-, and energy markets? Insights from Google searches." Energy Economics (2021): 105282.

Comment: You could ask Prange for his code. Or you could follow [Vargas (2008)](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/8027/1/MPRA_paper_8027.pdf) cited in Pranger (2021) as it gives the model's likelihood function in its appendix. Or perhaps better yet, ask Vargas to supply the code.

Comment: I already asked Prange, but no response yet. Thanks for your response, sir.